# Hambergur icon not displaying collapsed navbar items

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

**I am making a react application and using bootstrap navbar to make it mobile responsive but the hamburger icon is not displaying the items of navbar collapsed what is wrong here? any suggestions?**

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.1.3 library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Start of HTML code -->
<header id="header" className="fixed-top d-flex align-items-center header-transparent">
  <div className="container d-flex align-items-center navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-inverse ">

    <div className="logo mr-auto">
      <h1 className="text-light heading"><a href="/"><span>Prep</span></a></h1>
    </div>
    <button className="navbar-toggler  navbar-dark" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarmenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

    <nav className="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
      <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarmenu">
        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li className="nav-item"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li className="nav-item"><a href="#details">Features</a></li>
          <li className="nav-item"><a href="#team">Team</a></li>
          <li className="nav-item"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li className="nav-item"><a href="#faq">FAQs</a></li>
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/signup">Register</Link>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: why you use `className` and not `class=""`

Comment: they said they are using react

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for you . You can see it in your react code how it works . Because I haven't installed react now .But using botstrap I have done this. You can check .

here is code snippets:

```html
 <nav className='navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg bg-dark'>
        <a href="#" class="text-light navbar-brand">Prep</a>
    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarmenu"  aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarmenu">
        <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li className="nav-item"><a className='nav-link' href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li className="nav-item"><a className='nav-link' href="#details">Features</a></li>
            <li className="nav-item"><a className='nav-link' href="#team">Team</a></li>
            <li className="nav-item"><a className='nav-link' href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li className="nav-item"><a className='nav-link' href="#faq">FAQs</a></li>
            <li className="nav-item"><Link to="/signup">Register</Link></li>

        </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

This is the convinient way how you can fix this issue and its really easy. You are using jsx If this works fine I will be happy as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CDN links make sure you have included jQuery link and if you are using `npm install bootstrap` make sure you have imported bootstrap `import 'bootstrap';`